# Complex object within Complex object is undefined in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I have the following model in angular:

```
export default class ScheduleTriggerData {
    id: Guid;
    name: string;
    isAdvancedSchedule: boolean;
    schedule: string;

    schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel: SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel

    constructor(init?: Partial<ScheduleTriggerData>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel is:

```
export default class SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel {
    algorithm: string;

    constructor(init?: Partial<SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel>) {
       Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

I have binded the **algorithm** property of **SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel** with the view. On the **ngOnInit** of **.ts** file i have done:

```
this.bindToEditSlider = new ScheduleTriggerData();
```

Now, i am getting the error "Cannot read property algorithm of undefined" . What am i doing wrong ? I mean this thing does work in C# so what i am missing here. I am stuck at this so, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your schedule Trigger Data to :-

```
export default class ScheduleTriggerData {
    id: Guid;
    name: string;
    isAdvancedSchedule: boolean;
    schedule: string;

    schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel: SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel

    constructor(init?: Partial<ScheduleTriggerData>) {
       if(init){
        this.id = init.id;
        this.name = init.name;
        this.isAdvancedSchedule = init.isAdvancedSchedule;
        this.schedule = init.schedule;
        this.schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel = new SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel(init.schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel);
       } else {
        this.schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel = new SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel();  
       }
    }
}



export default class SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel {
    algorithm: string;

    constructor(init?: Partial<SchedulerAlgorithmRequestModel>) {
      if(init){
       Object.assign(this, init);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel' of undefined . . getting this error now

Comment: Cannot read property 'algorithm' of undefined . .getting this now

Comment: tried the updated code, getting the error "Cannot read property 'algorithm' of undefined" with updated code

Comment: @WaleedNaveed added one more thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216054/discussion-between-waleed-naveed-and-aakash-garg).

Answer (score 0):

this line call the constructor without arguments.

```
this.bindToEditSlider = new ScheduleTriggerData();
```

This constructor will have `undefined` in the `init` argument

```
export default class ScheduleTriggerData {
.......

    constructor(init?: Partial<ScheduleTriggerData>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

`Object.assign(this, undefined)` will not initialize the property `schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel` and it will stay `undefined`.
You need to initialize `schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel` somehow or change the binding so that it could handle the situation when `schedulerAlgorithmRequestModel` is `undefined`

Comment: Put break point on that line. See any undefined vars? Move in logic AfterViewInit an Angular component method.